# Prevent Apache from answering invalid requests

Tags: apache, security

I have an Apache web-server that acts as a web front-end for iPhone and iPad applications that communicate by POST and JSON only.

Is there any way to prevent Apache from answering requests that are invalid? I can see my error log is filled with attempts to open files such as /admin.php /index.php etc - files that don't exist on my server.

I believe this is possible with IIS, but can you do the same thing with Apache?

Basically I want the request to appear timed out unless you post exactly the right content to the right file - or at least if you do not request an existing file. This would make the server appear non-existing to everyone but my iPhone users as all communication is SSL and directories are not really guess-able.

I did disable the ServerTokens and all that, but I still get File not found etc. when I access the server requesting a random file, which is what these bots do constantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit what HTTP methods Apache responds to by using `mod_rewrite` to redirect or deny unwanted requests.

Note that JSON is not an HTTP method.   `GET, POST, PROPFIND` etc are HTTP method.  For a full list of HTTP methods please see: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

If your application truly does not need to honor `GET` requests, then you can block all other methods.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(POST) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

I've not tested this but it should block anything other than a POST method.  You can add multiple methods.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(POST|GET) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Would permit only `POST` and `GET`.

You may need to also specify 'Options FollowSymLinks` on some servers due to how rewrites are handled.

If you must permit `GET` requests, then you will see those not found errors. There is nothing that prevents someone from issuing a HTTP request for an object that does not exist.

Comment: Fair enough. It seems weird that the server must respond to something it cannot serve and that this behaviour cannot be changed.

Comment: And I am well aware that JSON is not a HTTP method - the server delivers JSON responses to POST requests. That's what I meant.