# How to block unwanted php requests in apache

Tags: php, apache

Our web application needs no php code and our apache has no php installed,
but there are annoying php requests from different unwanted sources all the time.

How can I configure apache to ignore them, that those requests don't spoil the apache error log.

As we have unrestricted access to the server, we do not need an htaccess file.

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147676/prevent-apache-from-answering-invalid-requests And https://perishablepress.com/protect-post-requests/ AND  http://www.blogtips.org/web-crawlers-love-the-good-but-kill-the-bad-and-the-ugly/  AND  http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-ip-address/.  But one thing :- It seems weird that the server must respond to something it cannot serve and that this behaviour cannot be changed

Comment: Basically, you don't want that 404s end up in Apache's error.log, right?

Comment: @Mjh Op does not say, but if it is Apache 2.4, it does not log 404 errors by default in error log. This is made to avoid logs filling with requests like these and the typical favicon missing 404 errors, etc.

Comment: It's rather pointless to only care about bogus traffic that requests for URls that end in  `.php`. You'll still get tons of requests for many other assorted stuff, from non-existing favicon.ico files to any other arbitrary location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this in your `httpd.conf` in your section where mod_rewrite is mentioned

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule \.php.* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This or `<FilesMatch \.php.*> Require all denied </FilesMatch>`

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the previous answer to forbid all php requests, you can also not log them with:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.php.*?" no_log
CustomLog /path/to/vh-access.log common env=!no_log
```